# selenium class span constantly changing python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need help to extract the text from a span class that is constantly changing. I have tried everything, Xpath, class name ... but I can never extract the text.
[image]

As you can see in the photo, I want to extract the number from the top left ("BB"). And below you can see that it is a span class. This price is constantly changing.
I have tried with

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath['/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[1]/span'].text
```

also

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="pane-legend-item-value-wrap"]').text
```

Xpath is supposed to have no problems ... but I can't extract the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Elements in `Tradingview` is in an `iframe`. The DOM keeps changing.

Below is the code. Sometimes it works with `options` and sometimes with `options1`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://www.binance.com/es/trade/ETH_USDT?layout=pro")
time.sleep(40) # To manually close the pop-ups, select "tradingview" and "Boillinger bands"

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@name,'tradingview')]"))

options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='chart-markup-table']//tr[1]//div[@class='pane-legend']//div[contains(@class,'study')]")
print("from options: {}".format(len(options)))
for opt in options:
    title = opt.find_element_by_xpath("./span[1]").get_attribute("innerText")
    value = opt.find_elements_by_xpath("./div//span[contains(@class,'item-value')]/span/*")
    valuelist = []
    for val in value:
        valuelist.append(val.get_attribute("innerText"))
    print(f"{title}: {valuelist}")

options1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-name='legend']/div[2]/div[2]/div[@data-name='legend-source-item']")
print("from options1: {}".format(len(options1)))
for opt in options1:
    title = opt.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'titleWrapper')]").get_attribute("innerText")
    value = opt.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'valueValue')]/*")
    valuelist = []
    for val in value:
        valuelist.append(val.get_attribute("innerText"))
    print(f"{title}: {valuelist}")
```

```
from options: 4
MA (7, close, 0): ['3449.2257']
MA (25, close, 0): ['3487.6052']
MA (99, close, 0): ['2713.4087']
BB (20, 2): ['3556.2910', '4026.2328', '3086.3492']
from options1: 0
```

Comment: it does not work, if you want you can try. It's binance, and the bollinger bands are the ones I'm trying to scrape. Could it have something to do with a graph?

Comment: @jlemosmusi-  Share the complete URL.

Comment: thanks @pmadhu  to be answered :) . this is the url https://www.binance.com/es/trade/ETH_USDT?layout=pro . if you can't visualize the (BB). You can add it above, next to 4h 1D down arrow (and then comes the button where you put BB and you already have it on the graph). In any case, it would be the same as extracting the MA (which is surely the one that appears to you)

Comment: @jlemosmusi -  I could not get `BB`. I see `MA(7)` and similar options. The `span` tag for the same `<span class="default-label-box" key="MA[0]Series" style="padding-right: 5px; color: rgba(241, 156, 56, 0.7); display: block;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">3373.51</font></font></span>`. Dint see any kind of `pane-legend`.

Comment: @jlemosmusi - In the screen shot which is the tag that you have highlighted.

Comment: @pmadhuit is the same MA or BB, they are similar options and have the same format. Try to bring the text of MA (that is, those inherit;">3373.51</font> which you have sent). Later I modify it in BB. But for example, I'm trying to scrape the MA and I can't . thanks for helping me. I really appreciate it very much :)

Comment: @jlemosmusi - Was able to select option `BB` still the DOM was different for me. I have updated the code. Hope its gonna help.

Comment: @pmadhuit I think I already know what the problem is. Note that your script works only in MA, but not in BB, it only works when you enter the chart "original" but not when you enter "tradingView". Could it be that the page overlaps in graphics and does not take the ones that TradingView brings?

Comment: @jlemosmusi - I have reupdated my answer.